# I cant put the latitude and longitude using navigator.geolocation into my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a website which shows the longitude and latitude using the browser's navigator feature. When i run the code below I get `Latitude:undefined` instead of `Latitude:[My latitude]`. Can anyone help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var la;
  var lg;

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    la = position.coords.latitude;
    lg = position.coords.longitude;
  }
  document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = "Latitude:" + la;
});
```

Comment: The `getCurrentPosition()` call is asynchronous, so the `document.getElementById(...` line *has* to go within the `showPosition()` function, after you define `la` and `lg`. I'd also advise that you move the `la` and `lg` definitions to a more local scope

Comment: I tried that, and now it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Yes it does. I presume you're calling `getLocation()` - even though your sample code doesn't show it? https://jsfiddle.net/smyy7e1m/

Comment: Yeah, I didn't call `getLocation()` because i thought that the `$(document).ready(function() {` line will do that for me automatically, once the page is loaded. It works now. Thank you!